# Working with Microsoft Translator API in Android

Tags: java, android, localization, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I am working with Microsoft Translator API in my app. I am unable to execute this code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Translate.setClientId("My client");
    Translate.setClientSecret("secret key");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button Trans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bTranslate);
    Trans.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {   
    //get the text entered
    EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserText);
    TextView output = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvTranslatedText);

    String In =input.getText().toString();
    //String Out;
    try {
        String Out = Translate.execute(In, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);
        input.setText(Out);
        output.setText(Out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTranslatedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etUserText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bTranslate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etUserText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Translate" 
        android:onClick="trans"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.translator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.translator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: while i installing "unfortunately,translator has stopped"  E/AndroidRuntime(2011): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate

Comment: Do you have the jar file in which the `Translate` class is present ? Is that jar added in the Android Dependencies section ?

Comment: mhrrm, `NoClassDefFoundError`s can be tricky. Double check your classpath, your eclipse build path settings (no ex- or inclusion patterns set!!) and your imported libraries

Comment: thanku for response i already imported the jar file            microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar and if i not import the jar i got a compile time error right.so i think this not a problem

Comment: if possible please once execute my code

Answer (score 0):

String In =input.getText().toString();

I think your problem is in the line above .. an object cannot contain capital letters .. so, change (In) into (in) .. worth the try